# dplyr and overlapping variable names with surrounding environment

Tags: r, dplyr

Let's say I have a (dplyr/tibble) data-frame/tbl constructed like so:

```
df <- data_frame(x = 1:10)
```

Now, I'd like to use this within a function that works with `df` via some dplyr verbs, like so:

```
myfun <- function(df, x) {
  x <- doSomeStuffTo(x)
  filter(df, x == x)
}
```

But this will always return the full `df`... I'm trying to figure out a way to implement scoping within a dplyr verb, something like:

```
filter_(df, ~x == x)
```

... which doesn't work, either. In some other languages, you might be able to achieve this via something like:

```
df.filter(this.x == x)
```

... where `this` refers to the `df` instance.

My only work-around so far is naming the function's variable like so:

```
myfun <- function(df, query_x) {
  query_x <- doSomeStuffTo(query_x)
  filter(df, x == query_x)
}
```

I suspect this is doable (without using a name like `query_x`) *somehow* with SE dplyr verbs (e.g. `filter_`), but I haven't stumbled upon the correct pattern yet. Anyone here have the answer?

Answer (score 2):

To dynamically build different dplyr commands you typically use the standard evaluation versions of the functions (the ones with the underscores) and the lazyeval package.  Here's how you could change your function

```
doSomeStuffTo <- function(x) {x+1}

myfun <- function(df, x) {
  x <- doSomeStuffTo(x)
  filter_(df, lazyeval::interp(~x == y, y=x))
}

df <- data_frame(x = 1:10)    
myfun(df,3)
```

but even in the interp we can't have `x==x` because it's not clear which `x` you want to replace. Both `filter(df, 3==x)` and `filter(df, x==3)` work with dplyr. You can have constants or column names on either side of the equality.

Comment: Might there be any good reason for not simply doing `y <- doSomeStuffTo(x); filter(df, x == y)`?

Comment: No. That's probably what I would have done. It's the easiest thing in my opinion but the OP wanted some other alternative.

Comment: Yeah, perhaps I should've rephrased the question. I _do_ know how to assign new variables names, but I don't know if I'm missing a scoping trick within (either SE or NSE) dplyr verbs to specify the exact scope of each variable mention.

Comment: Expressions are evaluated in a single environment (which may inherit from other environments). You can't explicitly pick and choose where to evaluate variables within a single expression. Your only choice is to use unambiguous variable names.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `filter_` you can pass logical expressions via `quote`:

```
myfun <- function(df, t) {
  df$x <- 5*df$x
  filter_(df, t )
}

> myfun(df, t= quote(x < 25) )
# A tibble: 4 x 1
      x
  <dbl>
1     5
2    10
3    15
4    20
```

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled into the same issue. Instead of wrangling with even more complex evaluations, it's usually easier to just rename the function argument. Like this:

```
myfun <- function(df, x) {
  x_ <- doSomeStuffTo(x)
  filter(df, x == x_)
}
```

This solution is still dangerous because we might hit another variable called `x_`. One can be defensive about this by checking the variable names in `df` and making sure to pick one that isn't there. Or more lazily, one can use very implausible variable names. I often use stuff like `_____temp`.

Maybe the new [**dplyr** 0.6.0](https://blog.rstudio.org/2017/04/13/dplyr-0-6-0-coming-soon/) evaluation system will handle this better. See the notes about the new system, **[tidyeval](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html)**.